# postgres: alter user not updating the password

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am setting up postgres on a docker container.

```
if [ "$POSTGRES_DB" != 'postgres' ]; then
  createSql="CREATE DATABASE $POSTGRES_DB;"
  echo $createSql | gosu postgres postgres --single -jE
  echo
fi

if [ "$POSTGRES_USER" != 'postgres' ]; then
  op=CREATE
else
  op=ALTER
fi

userSql="$op USER $POSTGRES_USER WITH SUPERUSER $pass;"
echo $userSql | gosu postgres postgres --single -jE
echo
```

Here's a part of my entry-point file.

So the premise is, say a user reuses a db image that already has a user `postgres`, but the password should be new. As you can see in the code, it's creating or altering a role based on whether `postgres` is present.

However, the password doesn't get updated. What could be possible reasons for this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a missing `commit`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, I didn't get it. What commit are you referring to?

Comment: If for some reason autocommit is turned off, the `CREATE` or `ALTER` statements need to be committed (by running `commit` afterwards) just like an UPDATE or INSERT statement

Comment: @relentless-coder Try `userSql="$op USER $POSTGRES_USER PASSWORD $pass;"`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh, never came across this. Let me try this, and I'll update you.

Comment: What exactly is in `$pass`? Maybe the command throws an error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe that just contains the password, and no, no error is thrown

Comment: Then that will be a syntax error. The correct syntax is `ALTER USER xxx WITH PASSWORD 'pwd'`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `autoCommit="SET AUTOCOMMIT ON;"`
    `echo $autoCommit | gosu postgres postgres --single -jE` this is giving me syntax error near "ON".